# Property 'chart' does not exist on type - ChartJS - Angular 13

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am very new to Angular, this is the first page I am developing using Angular. I am trying to implement the onClick functionality in ChartJS Bar graphs.

I am facing this error when I am trying to access `this.chart` in onClick of ChartJS,

```
Property 'chart' does not exist on type '_DeepPartialObject<CoreChartOptions<"bar"> & ElementChartOptions<"bar"> & PluginChartOptions<"bar"> & DatasetChartOptions<"bar"> & ScaleChartOptions<...> & BarControllerChartOptions>'.ts(2339)
```

Here is my code:

**graph.component.html**

```
<div class="chart-container">
     <canvas id="canvas">{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```

**graph.component.ts:**

```
        import { Inject, Injectable, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import {Chart, ChartConfiguration, ChartItem, registerables} from 'chart.js';

        @Component({
            selector: 'app-graphs',
            templateUrl: './graphs.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['./graphs.component.scss']
        })


        export class AssessmentGraphsComponent implements OnInit
        {
             constructor() { }

             chart: any;


        if(this.chart)
        {
            this.chart.destroy();
        }
        
        Chart.register(...registerables);
        this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
            type:'bar',
            data:
            {
                labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Something 1',
                        backgroundColor: 'lightblue',                                     
                        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',                  
                        data: [1, 1, 3, 5, 2]
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Something 2',
                        backgroundColor: 'green',                                
                        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        data: [1,2,3,4,5]
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Something 3',
                        backgroundColor: 'blue',                                   
                        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        data: [3,4,5,1,2]
                    },
                ]
            },
            options:
            {
                responsive: true,
                scales:
                {
                    x: {display: true},
                    y: {beginAtZero: true, display: true, ticks: {precision: 0}}
                },
                events: ['click'],
                onClick: function(e)
                {
                    console.log("CLICKED"); // This is working

                    // This line shows this error:
                    // Property 'chart' does not exist on type '_DeepPartialObject<CoreChartOptions<"bar"> & ElementChartOptions<"bar"> & PluginChartOptions<"bar"> & DatasetChartOptions<"bar"> & ScaleChartOptions<...> & BarControllerChartOptions>'.ts(2339)

                    const points = this.chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(e, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);

                    if (points.length)
                    {
                        const firstPoint = points[0];
                        const label = this.chart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
                        const value = this.chart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].data[firstPoint.index];
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I am using the code from this :

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementsateventformode-e-mode-options-usefinalposition

Can someone help me on this please.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this issue by using the third parameter you get in the onClick listener, this is the chartInstance already:

```js
onClick: (evt, activeEls, chartInstance) => {
  // Custom code
}
```